# RelativeLayout doesn't auto-adjust when keyboard is displayed despite setting windowSoftInputMode to "adjustResize"

Tags: android, android-edittext, onclicklistener, android-softkeyboard, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout saveCancelBar` that contains two buttons ("Save Title" and "Cancel) position at the bottom and should ideally move up by clicking my `EditText pageTitle`. In the `AndroidManifest`, I set my activity's `windowSoftInputMode` to `adjustResize` because I thought this will automatically move up `saveCancelBar` upon clicking `pageTitle` and displaying the soft keyboard but unfortunately didn't.

Oddly enough, `saveCancelBar` adjusts its position when it overlays another `RelativeLayout` (in my activity, it overlays `photoStoryNavbar`).

This is what the screen looks like and as you can see the `saveCancelBar` stayed at the bottom and was covered by the soft keyboard.

[image]

In another part of the activity, `saveCancelBar` automatically adjusts its position like this:

[image]

I am not sure why it did not adjust its position in the first screen like it did in the second screen since both screens are part of the same activity and use the same `onClickListener` for `pageTitle`

This is the XML for my activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="missingPrefix"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context="app.travelers.activity.AddPhotoActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/back_arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/arrow_left"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="36dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:maxLength="90"
            android:privateImeOptions="nm"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="16sp"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="24sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="4sp"
            android:textColor="@color/grey700"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/thin_border"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/grey700"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sort"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/header"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sort_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
                android:text="List View"
                android:textColor="@color/grey700"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sort_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/chevron_circle_down"
                android:textColor="@color/grey700"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/add_photo_layout"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/placeholder"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:minLines="0"
                    android:text="Add your first travel moment to your story"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/capture_photo_button"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                        android:paddingStart="5dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="170dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                        android:background="@drawable/green_pill_thick">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/capture_photo_icon"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:text="@string/camera"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                            android:textColor="@color/green500"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/capture_photo_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Capture Moment"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                            android:textColor="@color/green500"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textSize="14sp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/add_photo_button"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingStart="5dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                        android:layout_width="170dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                        android:background="@drawable/blue_pill_thick">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/add_photo_icon"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:text="@string/photo"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue500"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/add_photo_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Add from Gallery"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue500"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textSize="14sp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_view_layout"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="150dp"
            android:paddingBottom="50dp">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_view_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stackFromBottom="true"
                android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll">

            </ListView>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <!--Navbar-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/photo_story_navbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@drawable/navbar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

            <!-- Take Photo Button -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/nav_capture_button"
                android:layout_width="84dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/green_pill_button"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:clickable="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_capture_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:text="@string/camera"
                    android:textColor="@color/green500"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingEnd="5dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_capture_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Capture"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@color/green500"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Add from Gallery Button -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/nav_gallery_button"
                android:layout_width="84dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_pill"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:clickable="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_gallery_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:text="@string/photo"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue500"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingEnd="5dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_gallery_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Gallery"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue500"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!-- Review button -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/nav_review_button"
                android:layout_width="84dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/red_500_pill"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:clickable="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_review_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Review"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@color/red500"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_review_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:text="@string/angle_double_right"
                    android:textColor="@color/red500"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingStart="5dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/save_cancel_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@drawable/navbar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/save_title_btn"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_pill"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/save_title_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:text="Save Title"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#2196F3"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/cancel_title_btn"
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/grey_700_pill"
            android:layout_marginRight="105dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cancel_title_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#616161" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line into manifest file

`<activity
           ...............
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection"
          ........./>`

Answer (score 0):

Change adjustResize to adjustPan and stateHidden.

> android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"